# Google Documents List API - How to Publish a Document

Tags: gdata-api, gdata, google-docs-api, put, zend-gdata

I'm utterly lost as to how one can programmatically publish a Google Document (specifically a spreadsheet).

I've read the Google Documents List API Protocol Guide and have found this:

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#GettingRevisions

The next section of the article begins with 'Publishing documents by publishing a single revision' and this is where I found this example:

```
PUT /feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/revisions/revision_number
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 722
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
       xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007" gd:etag="W/"DkIBR3st7ImA9WxNbF0o."">
  <id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/resource_id/revisions/1</id>
  <updated>2009-08-17T04:22:10.440Z</updated>
  <app:edited xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">2009-08-06T03:25:07.799Z</app:edited>
  <title>Revision 1</title>
  <content type="text/html" src="https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docId=doc_id&amp;revision=1"/>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html"
      href="https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=doc_id&amp;revision=1"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
      href="https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/revisions/1"/>
  <author>
    <name>user</name>
    <email>user@gmail.com</email>
  </author>
  <docs:publish value="true"/>
  <docs:publishAuto value="false"/>
</entry>
```

I have been retrieving document list feeds and CRUDing worksheets but I cannot get the publishing to work nor do I understand how it is supposed to work. My basic setup for establishing a connection to my feed and preparing the data to be PUT is as follows:

```
<?php
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/library/');

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);


$theId = 'my-worksheet-id';

$user = "my-gmail-account-name";
$pass = "my-gmail-account-password";
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);

$service = new Zend_Gdata($client);


$xml = "<entry  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
        xmlns:docs='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007' gd:etag='W/\"DkIBR3st7ImA9WxNbF0o.\"'>

        <id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/spreadsheet:$theId/revisions/1</id>
        <updated>2009-08-17T04:22:10.440Z</updated>
        <app:edited xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'>2009-08-06T03:25:07.799Z</app:edited>
        <title>Revision 1</title>
        <content type='text/html' src='https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docId=$theId&amp;revision=1'/>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
            href='https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=$theId&amp;revision=1'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
            href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/spreadsheet:$theId/revisions/1'/>
        <author>
            <name>$user</name>
            <email>$user</email>
        </author>
        <docs:publish value='true'/>
        <docs:publishAuto value='false'/>
      </entry>";

$putURL = "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/spreadsheet:".$theId."/revisions/0";
$data = $service->put($xml, $putURL);
?>
```

Which results in a

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid request URI
```

Can someone help me out? Has anyone successfully published a Google Document programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the document has already been created and has a document id of XXXX

What you need to do is send a "PUT" request with specific headers, and XML (an entry describing your document) as the body, to a specific URL.

Since you are not changing any content of the doc (only the meta-data), your target URL will look like this...

https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/XXXX/revisions/0

The first thing you need to do is authenticate with the proper Google service.

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(GDOC_LOGIN, GDOC_PASS,'writely');
```

Use the returned object to grab your auth token.

```
$auth_token = $client->getClientLoginToken();
```

In Zend/Gdata/App.php is a helper function for executing the PUT request.
Prepare parameters for this method like so...

```
$method = "PUT";
$url ="https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/XXXX/revisions/0";
$headers['GData-Version'] = '3.0';
$headers['If-Match'] = '*';
$headers['Authorization'] = "GoogleLogin auth = $auth_token";
$headers['Content-Length'] = '380';
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/atom+xml';
$body = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007"
    xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
      term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet"/>
    <docs:publish value="true"/>
    <docs:publishAuto value="true"/>
</entry>
XML;
$contentType = "application/atom+xml";
$remainingRedirects = 99;
```

Then call the helper function...

```
$app = new Zend_Gdata_App();
$app->performHttpRequest($method, $url, $headers, $body, $contentType, $remainingRedirects);
```

Good luck!
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This has gotten me 99% of the way there. I am getting a document id error but the document is being published.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... where do I start?

First of all, your URL is incorrect. [(the resource ID you're using is for JSON/XML not URL)](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ResourceIDs)

you have

```
$putURL = "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/spreadsheet:".$theId."/revisions/0";
```

and you should have

```
$putURL = "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/$theId/revisions/0";
```

(you can omit . for concatenation if you use " as delimiters)

now there are other problems since you're manually creating a xml entry.

1. Your authorization header is missing.
2. In your XML you're using revision 1 but in your URL you have revision/0
3. value is manually written and I'm pretty sure you are not trying to publish a 2 years old file. Same for  and
4. MUST MATCH the retrieved etag or you won't be able to perform any PUT request.

Now you can change these values manually assigning variables but I think it's better to use Zend GData structured returned object.

In any case:

1. Retrieve from google the document you want to publish.
2. Find the correct entry (in this case the entry with the ID https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/spreadsheet:$theId/revisions/1)
3. change docs:publish value property to "true"
4. send a put request with the modified entry

that should work

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate and provide an example of this working? I am now getting an Invalid request URI error.

Answer (score 0):

I am new at Zend_Gdata myself but have sucessfully uploaded to Google Docs.

I don't know if this is what you are after but here is my code:

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
    'my@googleDocsEmail.address', 
    'MyPassword', 
    Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME
);
$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);

 $newDocumentEntry = $gdClient->uploadFile(
    $file, 
    null, 
    null, 
    Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI
);
```

I hope this helps,

Garry

Comment: He wants to publish an existing google document not upload a new one. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Google says that putted data is wrong and response you with code 400.

try to place this code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

before

```
<entry  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'...
```